# Minimize Multivariable Function Python SciPy

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize

I'm trying to minimize a function that has arguments `S1`, `S2`, `S3` and `n1`, `n2`, and `n3`. There are also weights: `w1`, `w2`, and `w3`.

This is the function:

```
f = (w1**2 * n1**2 + w2**2 * n2**2 + w3**2 * n3**2) / (w1**2 * S1**2 + w2**2 * S2**2 + w3**2 * S3**2 + 2*w1*S1*w2*S2 * 2*w1*S1*w2*S2 + 2*w2*S2*w3*S3)
```

I want to know given `S1`, `S2`, `S3`, `n1`, `n2`, and `n3`, what `w1`, `w2`, and `w3` will minimize `f`?

Here's my code so far:

```
def opt(S1, S2, S3, n1, n2, n3):
    xo = np.array([0,1,.01])
    from scipy.optimize import minimize
    signoise = lambda w1,w2,w3: (w1**2 * n1**2 + w2**2 * n2**2 + w3**2 * n3**2) / (w1**2 * S1**2 + w2**2 * S2**2 + w3**2 * S3**2 + 2*w1*S1*w2*S2 * 2*w1*S1*w2*S2 + 2*w2*S2*w3*S3)
    w1min, w2min, w3min = scipy.optimize.minimize(signoise, (.4, .2, .4))
    return w1min, w2min, w3min
```

scipy.optimize.minimize takes two arguments, the function and an initial guess. I don't know if it works for multivariable functions, because I'm getting the

```
error : <lambda>() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

Okay, I followed CodyKramer's suggestion. When I tested it with arbitrary values for S1, S2, S3, n1, n2, n3, I got all of this as an answer : status: 0 success: True njev: 1 nfev: 5 hess_inv: array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]) fun: 5.1874999894628917e-18 x: array([ 0.4, 0.2, 0.4]) message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.' jac: array([ -1.81249989e-17, -4.62499946e-17, 1.53125002e-17]) Is that last line the 'jac' the three numbers I was looking for?

Comment: The answer is the array `x` in your output. `jac` is the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) which is the  (basically) first derivative of `x`, and `hess` is the [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) which is (basically) the second derivative of `x`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that as written your `lambda` takes 3 arguments, not 1 argument (that happens to be a sequence with 3 elements). I would pull out your objective function into a standalone function

```
def signoise(w):
    w1, w2, w3 = w  # unpack your tuple into each variable
    # populate your S and n coefficients
    return w1**2 * n1**2 + w2**2 * n2**2 + w3**2 * n3**2) / (w1**2 * S1**2 + w2**2 * S2**2 + w3**2 * S3**2 + 2*w1*S1*w2*S2 * 2*w1*S1*w2*S2 + 2*w2*S2*w3*S3
```

Then you can modify your function to

```
def opt(S1, S2, S3, n1, n2, n3):
    xo = np.array([0,1,.01])
    from scipy.optimize import minimize
    return scipy.optimize.minimize(signoise, (.4, .2, .4))
```

Comment: Okay, I followed your suggestion. When I tested it with arbitrary values for S1, S2, S3, n1, n2, n3, I got all of this as an answer  : status: 0
  success: True
     njev: 1
     nfev: 5
 hess_inv: array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])
      fun: 5.1874999894628917e-18
        x: array([ 0.4,  0.2,  0.4])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
      jac: array([ -1.81249989e-17,  -4.62499946e-17,   1.53125002e-17])      Is that last line the 'jac' the three numbers I was looking for?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include that? Unfortunately all formatting is lost in the comment section so it's hard to parse that output visually